# Low Memory alert while recording video

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using cameraIntent for recording a video in my app. The available memory in my sdcard is around 1.2 GB, when i started recording it recorded for 40 mins but i did not get any alert sound or a message stating that memory is low.

what i want is show an alert message or a alert sound when the memory is low while recording the video

Answer (score 0):

I think you are record high Resolution... so its take large memory  .
Use this and set video size
parameter in [SetVideoSize(width, height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoSize%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: i dont want to set video size.. i want to show a alert message after the video is recorded

Comment: lets say i hav 200 mb available memory. i started recording the video after 5 mins the camera automatically stops the recording and asks to save or cancel due to low memory. what i want s to give a alert sound when it stops automatically due to low memory

Answer (score 0):

You can get from this.. and put condition when do you want to put msg.....

```
 public static long getUsedMemorySize() {

        long freeSize = 0L;
        long totalSize = 0L;
        long usedSize = -1L;
        try {
            Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
            freeSize = info.freeMemory();
            totalSize = info.totalMemory();
            usedSize = totalSize - freeSize;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return usedSize;

    }
```

Comment: Useing of this codeget the value of return mathod getUsedMemorySize
and put the condition when the usedSize is <= 200MB then generet a alertDialog and put Possitive and _ve Button like SAVE and CANCLE...